# how to reduce the time complexity?

Tags: python, time-complexity

**Following is the question:**
From a matrix of size n x m, we have to pick one element from each row to make a new array A of size N. we wish to find the minimum possible value of absolute difference between any two adjacent elements in the array A.
(Note:the element picked from row 1, will become A[1], element picked from row 2 will become A[2], and so on.)

**Sample ip(for 2 X 2 matrix) :**

```
8   4
6   8
```

**Sample op :**

```
0 #(8-8)
```

---

I have tried the following code but it is consuming a lot of time(5 sec) while the time limit is 1 sec.
Can anyone help in improving the complexity for the code ...

```
n,m=map(int,input().split())
l=[list(map(int,input().split())) for i in range(n)]
minimum=abs(l[0][0]-l[1][0])
for i in range(n):
if i+1<n:
    for j in range(m):
        for k in range(m):
            diff=abs(l[i][j]-l[i+1][k])
            if diff==0:
                minimum=diff
                break
            elif diff<minimum:
                minimum=diff
            else:
                continue
print(minimum)
```

Comment: You need to come up with a different algorithm, you have `O(m^2)`

Comment: @JeffMercado, There're 3 loops ...so it's nearly O(m^3) isn't it?

Comment: @AvishkaDambawinna Yeah, something like that. Either way, it's horribly inefficient

Comment: It is O(n*m^2). I do not see how this complexity can be reduced, but the implementation can be improved a lot (definitely enough to get under 1s). Also, there is an error in the algorithm which sometimes will lead to lower than real minimum result

Comment: Haven't given it too much thought but it kind of seems like something that could be solved with Max Flow, for which there are many efficient algorithms available

Comment: Or perhaps a greedy search tree method. Get an initial solution, and then explore other paths down the search tree pruning them as soon as they exceed the current minimum, or else taking them as the new minimum. This would by O(n*m^2) but would likely have better efficiency than current implementation due to pruning of large portions of the tree

Comment: If I correctly understand your problem, you can do this: Take two adjacent rows of the matrix. Sort them. Traverse this new sorted `2m` elements. The candidates for minimum difference should be adjacent (and from different rows). This should be `O(nm log m)`

Comment: @iamvegan Could you please explain the statement: "The candidates for minimum difference should be adjacent (and from different rows)."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**An idea**

Let's consider the following matrix:

```
8 4 3
6 8 1
```

Take row #1 and row #2 and make a vector. Since we want to also know what element belong to which row, pack these elements with their row number.

```
two_rows = [(8,1), (4,1), (3,1) (6,2), (8,2), (1,2)]
```

This means we have 8, 4, 3 from row #1, and 6, 8, 1 from row #2. Now sort this list (by the first value of tuples)

```
sorted_two_rows = [(1,2), (3,1), (4,1), (6,2), (8,1), (8,2)]
```

Next, traverse this list. Only consider the adjacent tuples from different rows

- `(1,2)` and `(3,1)`
- `(4,1)` and `(6,2)`
- `(6,2)` and `(8,1)`
- `(8,1)` and `(8,2)`

The rest is straightforward, just compute the absolute differences and record the minimum.

If you repeat this for all adjacent rows. You should find the overall minimum difference. This will take `O(nm log m)`.